# How to restrict creation of new version of item based on unnecessary column value change

Tags: sharepoint-server, version-history

We have SharePoint 2013 list, which consists of multiple columns. We have enabled version history for this list but our requirement is that we want to create new versions if specific column values are changed not for all. if any other column value changes then it will not create a new version. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done by the workflow. You can disable the versioning at the list level.
And create a replica of temp column for which you want the versioning. Whenever any items create to the list update the temp column with the original column value. Then write a condition in the workflow to these two columns values are not same:

```
if newTempColumnVale not equal to the original column then increase the version of that particular column - maybe you could use the item check-in action.
```

Comment: Thank you Rahaman, but we required versioning enable for the list. As other applications are integrated with SharePoint and using this versions.aspx page so it's quit difficult to disable versioning...also I did tried to edit versions.apsx page but it's not worked.